# I need to upload extra folders while publishing a python package

Tags: python, setuptools

I need to add few files with my python file to publish this is because iam reading texts from that file. Is there any way to do so?.
Here is my setup.py

````
  
# reading long description from file
with open('DESCRIPTION.txt') as file:
    long_description = file.read()
  
  
# specify requirements of your package here
REQUIREMENTS = ['']
  
# some more details
CLASSIFIERS = [
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ]
  
# calling the setup function 
setup(name='create-flask-project-cli',
      version='1.0.0',
      description='Create flask project with html and css ready using cli.',
      long_description=long_description,
      url='https://github.com/logan0501/create-flask-project-cli.git',
      author='Loganathan',
      author_email='logan05012001@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['flaskcli'],
      classifiers=CLASSIFIERS,
      install_requires=REQUIREMENTS,
      keywords='flaskapp cli html css flaskcli',
        entry_points ={
            'console_scripts': [
                'flaskcli = flaskcli.main:main'
            ]
        },
      )```
````

Comment: Did you mean [support for data files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html)? [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#declaring-required-dependency) is for packages (dependencies).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+add+package+files, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package_data